# Starting Django on a Linux server

Tags: python, django, twisted

Ok, i have created a nice Django app on my server

Obvioulsy I could do ./managy.py runserver 0:8000

But that's not really robust enough for production. I have constructed this code to start it

```
def server(application, port):
    """
    Application is the FLASK application object
    """
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.web.server import Site
    from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource

    resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), application)
    site = Site(resource)

    reactor.listenTCP(port, site, interface="0.0.0.0")
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from oms.wsgi import application
    server(application, 8100)
```

I should also show the oms.wsgi file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "oms.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This seems work on (on a different port) but the problem is that all fancy formatting is gone. What's the recommended way to start server in a production environment?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure your static file handling,  see [Managing static files (CSS, images) at the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't need to write that first file.  Instead,

```
twistd -n web --wsgi oms.wsgi.application
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in something production worthy I would suggest using django with uWSGI/nginx. Here are the [docs for getting started](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). After you're done hooking up uwsgi you can utilize nginx

Comment: This tutorial is pretty great in terms of both, helping you understand the concept, as well as getting your app up and running. I've successfully deployed and am maintaining 2 different apps on servers that I set up only by following this tutorial and tweaking some other things

Comment: I found the tutorial a bit terse and in particular at the start not very detailed. http://perlmaven.com/deploying-pyton-with-uwsgi-on-ubuntu-13-10 This tutorial explains better how to start the uwsgi service. However, this seems to be the correct route down although I would have loved to stick to twisted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use **Nginx + UWSGi** in your production environment. It's one of the best performance firendly combination that is easy to setup and manage.
That's what they use at [Disqus](https://disqus.com/). Now try to imagine how much request they get each day... It must be pretty stable.